# how do I use Remote Binary Protocol in cutter

Tags: radare2, remote

how do I use Remote Binary Protocol I tried to connect to gdbserver through the normal method but it would just hang and not connect. I let it go like that for 1 hour

Comment: What settings did you use? Did you do any further debugging of the connection?

Comment: settings:
gdbserver localhost:2000

I can connect to it with radare2 just not cutter hopes this helps i'm new to re